# Best way to manage trasactions with Promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I'm creating an utility class for NodeJs to help me manage database transactions.

My idea is to create a method like this:

```js
transactionBlock(params) {
    let _db;
    return mySqlConnector.getConnection(params.db)
        .then(db => {
            _db = db;
            console.log(`beginTransaction`);
            return db.beginTransaction()
        })
        .then(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(_db);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(`roolback`);
            _db.rollback();
        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log(`commit`);
            _db.commit();
        })
}
```

and use it like this:

```js
const params = {db:"my_db"};
transactionBlock(params)
    .then(db =>{
        console.log(`do query 1`);
        db.insert(....)
        console.log(`do query 2`);
        db.insert(....)
        console.log(`do query 3`);
        db.insert(....)
    })
```

I was hoping it would work, but obviously the result is the following:

```
beginTransaction
commit
do query 1
do query 2
do query 3
```

do you think it is possible to create a function `transactionBlock` that returns a promise where user can do the queries and finally, if all the queries are all ok, the function `transactionBlock` do the commits?

I use this: npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql

Thanks
bye

Comment: It looks like all the utility functions are already returning Promises. Which means you can use `await` to run commands in order if you put them inside an async function.

Comment: Are you using this lib? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysqlconnector

Comment: @eol i use this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem with your current approach is that `finally()` **always** runs, whether the promise chain resolves or rejects so you definitely don't want to be committing the transaction there.

I see only one option here... require a callback function representing the body of the transaction.

In general, I'd also advise using `async / await` syntax for readability.

```js
const transactionBlock = async (connectionName, txBody) => {
  const db = await mySqlConnector.getConnection(connectionName);
  await db.beingTransaction();
  try {
    await txBody(db);
    console.log("commit");
    return db.commit(); // all good, commit
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("rollback", err);
    await db.rollback();
    // keep the rejection chain going by re-throwing the error or a new one
    throw err; // or perhaps `new Error("DB error: " + err.message)`
  }
};
```

Called like this

```js
try {
  await transactionBlock("my_db", async (db) => {
    console.log(`do query 1`);
    await db.insert(/* ... */);
    console.log(`do query 2`);
    await db.insert(/* ... */);
    console.log(`do query 3`);
    await db.insert(/* ... */);
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.error("oh no, something went wrong", err);
}
```

---

If you were using Typescript, the following interfaces and types would ensure smooth operation

```ts
type TxBody = (db: Connection) => Promise<void>;
type TransactionBlock = (
  connectionName: string,
  txBody: TxBody
) => Promise<void>;

const transactionBlock: TransactionBlock = async (connectionName, txBody) => {
  // ...
};
```

Comment: i hope to do without using an internal callback, but your solution work!!! thanks @Phil